# DC/OS SMACK cluster resource management

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am trying to set DC/OS Spark-Kafka-Cassandra cluster using 1 master and 3 private AWS m3.xlarge instances (each having 4 processors, 15GB RAM).

I have questions regarding some strange behaviour I have incurred in the spike I did several days ago.

On each of the private nodes I have following **fixed** resources reserved (I speak about CPU usage, memory is not the issue)

- 0.5 CPUs for Cassandra on **each node**
- 0.3 - 0.5 CPUs for Kafka one **each node**
- 0.5 CPUs is the Mesos overhead (I simply see in DC/OS UI that it is occupied 0.5CPUs more than the summation of all the services that are running on a node -> this probably belongs to some sort of Mesos overhead)
- rest of the resources I have available for running Spark jobs (around 2.5 CPUs)

Now, I want to run 2 streaming jobs, so that they run on **every node** of the cluster. This requires me to set in *dcos spark run* command that number of executors is 3 (although I have 3 nodes in the cluster), as well as that number of CPU cores is 3 (it is impossible to set 1 or 2,because as far as I see minimum CPUs per executor is 1). Of course, for each of the streaming jobs, 1 CPU in the cluster is occupied by the driver program.

> First strange situation that I see is that instead of running 3 executors with 1 core each, Mesos launches 2 executors on 2 nodes where one has 2 CPUs, while the other has 1 CPU. There is nothing launched on the 3rd node **even though** there were enough resources. How to force Mesos to run 3 executors on the cluster?
>
> Also, when I run 1 pipeline with 3 CPUs, I see that those CPUs are blocked, and cannot be reused by other streaming pipeline, even though they are not doing any workload. Why Mesos can not shift available resources between applications? Isn't that the main benefit of using Mesos? Or maybe simply there are not enough resources to be shifted?

**EDITED**

Also the question is can I assign less than one CPU per Executor?

Kindest regards,

Srdjan

Comment: So, what's the actual question?

Comment: End of first paragraph in yellow:
How to force Mesos to run 3 executors on the cluster?

End of second paragraph in yellow:
Why Mesos can not shift available resources between applications? Isn't that the main benefit of using Mesos? Or maybe simply there are not enough resources to be shifted?